# Quantum entanglement in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement

What is the explanation of the quantum entanglement in the quantum field theory framework?

Comment: Check this out https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993

Comment: What do you mean by "explanation"? Entanglement is the same in any quantum system, be it of non-relativistic particles or relativistic fields.